# Can't boot LiveUSB in Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, live-usb, ubuntu-gnome

I am attempting to dual boot my HP machine that came pre-installed with Windows 8.1. I am trying to dual boot it with Ubuntu Gnome 64-bit version.

So far,
I have disabled fast startup from Control Panel,
I have disabled secure boot from the BIOS.
I have made a LiveUSB with UNetBootin, as recommended.
I have set the boot priority in UEFI mode to have USB devices at the top.

However, I cannot boot into LiveUSB.

How do I boot into LiveUSB to finish installing Ubuntu Gnome?

Comment: What Model is your HP machine?

Comment: @Mitch [HP Pavilion 15 p105nx](http://www8.hp.com/sa/en/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=7547087#!tab=features)

Comment: Have you tried disabling UEFI?

Comment: @Mitch There is no option to disable UEFI. There is one that allows to enable BIOS support, which I tried. I used f9 to change boot order and point to my USB but to no avail. :)

Answer (score 1):

First create your Windows system recovery DVDs from the HP support assistant and then delete the recovery partition that would be around 20GB

If you want more space for your Ubuntu installation than shrink the windows partition using Windows administrative tools then computer management then disk management

Now you will have enough space to install Ubuntu as UEFI only.

Enable secure UEFI boot in your BIOS and whenthe system is just booting press <kbd>F9</kbd> and choose boot from Live USB as `EFI` and install Ubuntu. 
Choose "Something else" during the installation and create an `ext4` partition and mount it on `/`. Create `swap` at least equal to the size of your RAM and no more then twice your RAM.

Then the system will ask you to create 100MB partition more and told you to marked as boot create that also after finishing installation go to BIOS and enable legacy mode also just when system is booting press <kbd>F9</kbd> it will show you choice of the operating system to boot `osbootmanager` is for Windows and Ubuntu choose any one and boot if you will not choose anything windows will boot.

**Note: Preinstalled Windows 8.1 is installed as UEFI in a way that even without secure boot UEFI,boot-loader of Windows can boot as legacy also.**

If you don’t like this method you can download the `bootnext` utility for dual boot after install

http://www.boyans.net/blog/download-bootnext/

However I’ve not downloaded it as of now just registered and waiting I am booting as what I’ve described as I am also using HP-15 notebook

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed in differents installations that some "UEFI" not let you install boot OS, so you can install Linux first and then install Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As a last-ditch attempt, I burned a LiveCD and voila I could boot into Ubuntu. Not sure if it is a problem with the USB or the laptop but it worked.

Posting this from my Ubuntu 14.10